# Upstart / init script not working

Tags: init, upstart

I'm trying to create a service / script to automatically start and controll my nodejs server, but it doesnt seem to work at all.

First of all, I used this source as main reference http://kvz.io/blog/2009/12/15/run-nodejs-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-karmic/

After testing around, I minimzed the content of the actual file to avoid any kind of error, resulting in this (the bare minimum, but it doesnt work)

```
description "server"
author      "blah"

start on started mountall
stop  on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 99 5

script
  export HOME="/var/www"

  exec nodejs /var/www/server/server.js >> /var/log/node.log 2>&1
end script
```

The file is saved in `/etc/init/server.conf`

when trying to start the script (as root, or normal user), I get:

```
root@iof304:/etc/init# start server
start: Job failed to start
```

Then, I tried to check my syntax with `init-checkconf`, resulting in:

```
$ init-checkconf /etc/init/server.conf 
File /etc/init/server.conf: syntax ok
```

I tried different other things, like `initctl reload-configuration` with no result.

What can I do? How can I get this to work? It can't be that hard, right?

Comment: and you're sure that you have a file at /usr/local/bin/nodejs?

Comment: @MattPileggi Damn, you're right... it's missing. Hm, strange, I remember using nodejs that way - let me try something else. Result: no change - I changed the command directly to `nodejs`, and even removed the `sudo -u` part to execute as root - nothing changed. I tried to call the command directly over console - that works.

Comment: Sorry not sure what else to look at.  I have all of my init scripts  setup to use Forever - which takes care of keeping it running.  Did you look into that at all?

Comment: Anything in /var/log/messages or boot.log about the job failed message??

Comment: Any updates, I'm getting this too!

Comment: Just got the same problem. The script executes fine manually. The upstart job just fails though and leaves no traces (logs) unfortunately.

Comment: Any updates on this? I've runned into the same problem trying to demonize Faye. Same error, no log traces as well!

Comment: Is there anything in /var/log/upstart/ ?

Comment: is this still unsolved?

Answer (score 0):

This is what our typical startup script looks like. As you can see we're running our node processes as user nodejs. We're also using the pre-start script to make sure all of the log file directories and .tmp directories are created with the right permissions.

```
#!upstart
description "grabagadget node.js server"
author      "Jeffrey Van Alstine"

start on started mysql
stop on shutdown
respawn

script
    export HOME="/home/nodejs"
    exec start-stop-daemon --start --chuid nodejs --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/nodejs/grabagadget.pid --startas /usr/bin/node -- /var/nodejs/grabagadget/app.js --environment production >> /var/log/nodejs/grabagadget.log 2>&1
end script

pre-start script
    mkdir -p /var/log/nodejs
    chown nodejs:root /var/log/nodejs
    mkdir -p /var/run/nodejs
    mkdir -p /var/nodejs/grabagadget/.tmp

    # Git likes to reset permissions on this file, but it really needs to be writable on server start 
    chown nodejs:root /var/nodejs/grabagadget/views/layout.ejs
    chown -R nodejs:root /var/nodejs/grabagadget/.tmp

    # Date format same as (new Date()).toISOString() for consistency
    sudo -u nodejs echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Starting" >> /var/log/nodejs/grabagadget.log
end script

pre-stop script
    rm /var/run/nodejs/grabagadget.pid
    sudo -u nodejs echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Stopping" >> /var/log/nodejs/grabgadget.log
end script
```

Answer (score -1):

As of Ubuntu 15, upstart is no longer being used, see systemd.

Comment: I don't know why this has been voted down. It solved the issue for me. The other answer above applies to a superseded system, anyone setting up a new system needs to know this no longer applies.